# Netplan bridge issue

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, netplan

I am trying to create a bridge using Netplan.
I copied this part of [the guide](https://netplan.io/examples#bridging).

But it gives me an error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# netplan generate
Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 9 column 10: br0: interface eth0 is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

To reference the `eth0` interface as an interface in the bridge, you must also declare that physical interface in your yaml, even if you have no other configuration to attach to it.  I.e.:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - eth0
```

The netplan.io example should be updated to reflect this.

Comment: This seems to be working. How about using static configuration ?

Comment: static configuration meaning what, exactly?

Comment: I mean static configuration for bridge instead of Dhcp .

Comment: You configure a static address on a bridge the same way you configure it on an ethernet, just put the config under the right device: https://netplan.io/examples#dhcp-and-static-addressing